# I can't get my cover using facebook graph api v3.0

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am building social networking mobile app using Ionic Framework 3.
I have to get user's cover to make the profile screen.
I could get it using facebook graph api v2.12.
But I can't get it using v3.0 .
Can anyone help me what the reason is?

Please check this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWU18.png

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/cover-photo/

Comment: could you explain what means of {fieldname_of_type_UserCoverPhoto}?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Not sure why this has so many downvotes. Facebook has not been clear that there is no replacement for the `cover` field. This is beside the fact that after everything they have thrown at devs in 2018, removing `cover` is beyond frustrating and entirely unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the changelog, the `cover` field is deprecated and will not work in v3.0 of the Graph API anymore:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version3.0#gapi-change

Comment: Hi Can I ask one more question?
link field also has been deprecated. But it can be used when I get user_link permission. right?
Could I use cover as well by getting any permission?
Thank you.

Comment: no, there is no permission for it. the changelog specifically mentions a new permission for the link.